# How to validate multiple records insertion in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My app has a form where I insert multiple records, each record is a new form. I want to validate each field in each form I tried to use validate function but I am confused how to do it for multiple records insert ? For this project I am using laravel 5.2.

Store Function For Multiple Insert

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required|min:4',
            'fname' => 'required',
            'rollno' => 'required|unique:students'
        ]);
        $input = $request->all();
        $condition = $input['name'];
        foreach ($condition as $key => $condition) {
            $student = new Student;
            $student->name = $input['name'][$key];
            $student->fname = $input['fname'][$key];
            $student->rollno = $input['rollno'][$key];
            $student->obtainedmarks = $input['obtainedmarks'][$key];
            $student->totalmarks = $input['totalmarks'][$key];
            $student->percentage = $input['percentage'][$key];
            $student->save();
        }
        return Redirect::to('/allresults');

}
```

View For Inserting data

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.add').click(function () {
            var n = ($('.resultbody tr').length - 0) + 1;
            var tr = '<tr><td class="no">' + n + '</td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" class="name form-control" name="name[]" value="{{ old('name') }}"></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="text" class="fname form-control" name="fname[]" value="{{ old('fname') }}"></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="text" class="rollno form-control" name="rollno[]" value="{{ old('rollno') }}"></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="text" class="obtainedmarks form-control" name="obtainedmarks[]" value="{{ old('email') }}"></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="text" class="totalmarks form-control" name="totalmarks[]"></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="text" class="percentage form-control" name="percentage[]"></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" value="x"></td></tr>';
            $('.resultbody').append(tr);
        });

        $('.resultbody').delegate('.delete', 'click', function () {
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });

        $('.resultbody').delegate('.obtainedmarks , .totalmarks', 'keyup', function () {
            var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
            var obtainedmarks = tr.find('.obtainedmarks').val() - 0;
            var totalmarks = tr.find('.totalmarks').val() - 0;

            var percentage = (obtainedmarks / totalmarks) * 100;
            tr.find('.percentage').val(percentage);
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Add Results</div>
                @if(count($errors) >0 )
                    <ul>
                        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                            <li>{{$error}}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                @endif
                <div class="panel-body">
                   <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/result') }}">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Student Name</th>
                                    <th>Father Name</th>
                                    <th>Roll No</th>
                                    <th>Obtained Marks</th>
                                    <th>Total Marks</th>
                                    <th>%</th>
                                    <th>Delete</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody class="resultbody">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="no">1</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="name form-control" name="name[]" value="{{ old('name') }}">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="fname form-control" name="fname[]" value="{{ old('fname') }}">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="rollno form-control" name="rollno[]" value="{{ old('rollno') }}">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="obtainedmarks form-control" name="obtainedmarks[]" value="{{ old('email') }}">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="totalmarks form-control" name="totalmarks[]">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="percentage form-control" name="percentage[]">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" value="x">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>    
                        <center><input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary add" value="Add New Item">   
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" value="Submit"></center>
                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div><!-- First Row End -->
</div> <!-- Container End -->

@endsection
```

**Update :** In the view you will notice there is a button when the user click on that "add new" it adds new row row I want to validate all the rows, each row contains a record. 
[image]

Comment: you can use wildcard validation

Comment: can you elaborate it @NahidBinAzhar

Comment: see the doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#validating-arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel 5.2 comes with bundle of ready features, for array validations you can take a look on [Validating Arrays](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#validating-arrays)

In your case you should try :

```
   $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name.*' => 'yourRules',
            'fname.*' => 'yourRules',
            'rollno.*' => 'yourRules',
            'obtainedmarks.*' => 'yourRules',
            'totalmarks.*' => 'yourRules'
        ]);

  if($validator->fails()) {
            return back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator->errors());
  }
```

**Another Solution:**

The above solution is perfect and latest one, specially for Laravel 5.2 users. You can also try

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'array',
    //and your other rules here
]);
```

After that use Validator `each` method to apply your defined rules to each element of the array.

```
$validator->each('name','yourRule');
```

Comment: I tried this before but the whole problem was that \ thing over there with Validator Class. Solved !

Answer (score 7):

I think you can do this to validate your array input.

```
'input_name.*' => 'rules'
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#validating-arrays

So in your case this:

```
$this->validate($request,[
     'name.*'   => 'required|min:4',
     'fname.*'  => 'required',
     'rollno.*' => 'required|unique:students'
 ]);
```

Comment: It outputs `ErrorException in helpers.php line 523:
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\ngresulty\resources\views\students\addresult.blade.php)` error

Comment: That's because you are trying to get the 'old input'. But since it's an array you need to do it like this.
`{{ old('name.index') }}`.

Comment: I tried to put 0 as index but still same error @z3r0ck

Comment: i even removed the value = old('name index ) thing but still the same error.

Comment: did you remove all the old inputs that is an array?
I was able to reproduce the error and in my case it was the old('input') call that caused it.

Comment: Yes i also saw that in a video but it is not working with me , i removed all old('input') from the code.

Comment: It got to be that. Perhaps try `dd($erros);` at the beginning of your view file and see if you get the errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115344/discussion-between-z3r0ck-and-web-engineer).

Comment: Your issue may be related to the number of rows. The blade is rendering with a single row, so a return with more than one row will not work. Moreover, the javascript include blade syntax and that will never work either.

Answer (score 2):

Form input arrays make things a little more complicated. You are making mistakes on various levels:

- Not accounting for row index position.
- Blade renders only one row when there may be more.
- Blade syntax in javascript will never work.
- Never calling your validator.
- Saving valid records without considering that you may have to return the user if one of the records is invalid.

  - Choosing to return only invalid rows adds some more work but can be done.

Try the following as a start point. I didn't have time to test this all now but it follows logic I have successfully used many times.

#### view

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.add').click(function () {
            var n = $('.resultbody tr').length - 0;
            var n_adj = n + 1;
            var tr = '<tr><td class="no">' + n_adj + '</td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" class="name form-control" name="name[n]" value=""></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="text" class="fname form-control" name="fname[n]" value=""></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="text" class="rollno form-control" name="rollno[n]" value=""></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="text" class="obtainedmarks form-control" name="obtainedmarks[n]" value=""></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="text" class="totalmarks form-control" name="totalmarks[n]"></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="text" class="percentage form-control" name="percentage[n]"></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" value="x"></td></tr>';
            $('.resultbody').append(tr);
        });

        $('.resultbody').delegate('.delete', 'click', function () {
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });

        $('.resultbody').delegate('.obtainedmarks , .totalmarks', 'keyup', function () {
            var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
            var obtainedmarks = tr.find('.obtainedmarks').val() - 0;
            var totalmarks = tr.find('.totalmarks').val() - 0;

            var percentage = (obtainedmarks / totalmarks) * 100;
            tr.find('.percentage').val(percentage);
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Add Results</div>
                @if(count($errors) >0 )
                    <ul>
                        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                            <li>{{$error}}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                @endif
                <div class="panel-body">
                   <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/result') }}">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Student Name</th>
                                    <th>Father Name</th>
                                    <th>Roll No</th>
                                    <th>Obtained Marks</th>
                                    <th>Total Marks</th>
                                    <th>%</th>
                                    <th>Delete</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody class="resultbody">

                                @for ($i = 0; $i < isset($row_count) ? $row_count : 1; $i++)
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="no">{{ $i+1 }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="name form-control" name="name[]" value="{{ old('name['.$i.']', null) }}">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="fname form-control" name="fname[]" value="{{ old('fname['.$i.']', null) }}">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="rollno form-control" name="rollno[]" value="{{ old('rollno['.$i.']', null) }}">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="obtainedmarks form-control" name="obtainedmarks[]" value="{{ old('obtainedmarks['.$i.']', null) }}">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="totalmarks form-control" name="totalmarks[]" value="{{ old('totalmarks['.$i.']', null) }}">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="percentage form-control" name="percentage[]" value="{{ old('percentage['.$i.']', null) }}">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" value="x">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                @endfor

                            </tbody>
                        </table>    
                        <center><input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary add" value="Add New Item">   
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" value="Submit"></center>
                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div><!-- First Row End -->
</div> <!-- Container End -->

@endsection
```

#### store()

```
use Validator;

// ...

public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $validation_rules = [
            'name' => 'required|min:4',
            'fname' => 'required',
            'rollno' => 'required|unique:students'
        ];

        $validation_messages = [
            // add custom error messages
        ];

        $name = $request->input('name');
        $fname = $request->input('fname');
        $rollno = $request->input('rollno');
        $obtainedmarks = $request->input('obtainedmarks');
        $totalmarks = $request->input('totalmarks');
        $percentage = $request->input('percentage');

        // number of rows submitted (use a required value)
        $n = count($names);

        // track valid student records
        $students = [];

        for ($i=0; $i < $n; $i++) {
            $data = [
                'name' => $name[$i],
                'fname' => $fname[$i],
                'rollno' => $rollno[$i],
                'obtainedmarks' => $obtainedmarks[$i],
                'totalmarks' => $totalmarks[$i],
                'percentage' => $percentage[$i]
            ];
            $validator = Validator::make($data, $validation_rules, $validation_messages);

            if ($validator->fails()) {
                // redirect back to form
                return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->all())->with('errors', '$validator->errors());
            }

            $students[] = $data;
        }

        foreach ($students as $row) {
            Student::create($row);
        }

        return redirect('/allresults');

}
```

Comment: *Not accounting for row index position*. I completely disagree with that statement. Look at this: http://adamwathan.me/2016/04/06/cleaning-up-form-input-with-transpose/

Comment: @ÁlvaroGuimarães Transpose looks interesting... What part of the statement do you disagree with? Look at the question asked and please point out where the code is either using Transpose or is specifying the row index as needed for a dynamic amount of rows.

Comment: My comment looked rude, it was not my intention, sorry. The statement I disagree is: "Not accounting for row index position". Your answer is correct, but I don't think you NEED to control the row index position.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGuimarães I appreciate your consideration but assure you that your comment was not read by me as rude. Once I reached the code I have shared I stopped testing so I can't say that it won't work without a specified row index position, it just seems that blade has to create one row at a time and I'm not sure how `old()` would know which row was relevant in the current loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$failed = false;
$errors = [];
        foreach($data['name'] as $key => $val){

            $v = Validator::make($val, [
                        'name' => 'unique:users'
             ]);



             if ($validator->fails()) {
                $failed = true;
                 $error = [
                     'msg' => $v->errors()->all(),
                     'number' => $val['name'],
                 ];
                 array_push($errors, $error); 
             }

        }

if($failed == true){
    return['msg' => false, 'data' => $errors];
}
```

Try this one :)

Comment: Create multiple Validator instance isn't the best solution, Laravel can validate arrays

Answer (score 0):

### For Multi record validation use like this with custom message with record number

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Modules\Export\ExportBooking;

use App\Rules\PhoneRule;
use App\Traits\ApiResponser;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;


class ExportBookingCreateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    use ApiResponser;

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'booking_date' => 'required|date',
            'exp_organization_id' => ['required','integer', Rule::exists('organization', 'id')->where('is_export', 1) ],
            'marketing_person_id' => 'required|integer|exists:marketing_person,id',
            'customer_id' => 'required|integer|exists:customer,id',

            'exp_booking_dtl' => 'required',
        ];

        $exp_booking_dtl = $this->input('exp_booking_dtl');

        foreach ($exp_booking_dtl as $rowNumber => $item) {
            $rules["exp_booking_dtl.{$rowNumber}.product_id"] = "required|integer|exists:product,id";
            $rules["exp_booking_dtl.{$rowNumber}.product_sticker_id"] = "required|integer|exists:product_sticker,id";
            $rules["exp_booking_dtl.{$rowNumber}.po_number_id"] = "nullable|integer|exists:po_number,id";
            $rules["exp_booking_dtl.{$rowNumber}.qty"] = "required|numeric|gt:0";
        }
        return $rules;
    }
    public function messages()
    {
        $messages = [];
        $exp_booking_dtl = $this->input('exp_booking_dtl');

        foreach ($exp_booking_dtl as $rowNumber => $item) {

            $messages["exp_booking_dtl.{$rowNumber}.product_id.required"] = "Booking Detail Rec-".($rowNumber+1).": Product is required.";
            $messages["exp_booking_dtl.{$rowNumber}.product_id.exists"] = "Booking Detail Rec-".($rowNumber+1).": Invalid Product.";

            $messages["exp_booking_dtl.{$rowNumber}.product_sticker_id.required"] = "Booking Detail Rec-".($rowNumber+1).": Product Sticker is required.";
            $messages["exp_booking_dtl.{$rowNumber}.product_sticker_id.exists"] = "Booking Detail Rec-".($rowNumber+1).": Invalid Product Sticker.";

            $messages["exp_booking_dtl.{$rowNumber}.po_number_id.exists"] = "Booking Detail Rec-".($rowNumber+1).": Invalid PO Number.";

            $messages["exp_booking_dtl.{$rowNumber}.qty.required"] = "Booking Detail Rec-".($rowNumber+1).": Qty is required.";
            $messages["exp_booking_dtl.{$rowNumber}.qty.gt"] = "Booking Detail Rec-".($rowNumber+1).": Qty must be greater than :value.";
        }
        return $messages;
    }
    public function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(
            $this->set_response(null, 422, 'error', $validator->errors()->all(), new Request($this->request->all()))
        );
    }
}
```