# How to validate content of Excel file properly, when I use Maatwebsite\Excel package and it's ToCollection concern?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I'm trying to import new users to the system, using Maatwebsite\Excel package. Default package concern ToModel is not suitable for me, because I need to assign default role for each imported user and to send an email for him/her. I am trying to use ToCollection concern, as it is described in the last chapter of this documentation page: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html . The problem is that I can't validate the contents of Excel file properly: error messages don't appear at all. How can I validate the contents of Excel file properly, when I use Maatwebsite\Excel package and it's ToCollection concern?

Maybe do you know different approaches how to set a role for the user and send email after import of each user?

```
<?php

/* My controller and action which calls import of users: */


/* used namespaces go here */

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function updateClient(UserClientRequest $request)
    {
        /* Client entity is being updated here, instead of this comment */

        // here I try to import users from *.xls file:
        $errors = [];
        if ($request->hasFile('file_to_import_users')) {
            $usersImport = new UsersImport($client->id);
            $usersImport->import($request->file('file_to_import_users'));
            foreach ($usersImport->failures() as $failure) {
                foreach ($failure->errors() as $error) {
                    $errors[] = $error;
                }
            }
        }

        return redirect()->route('profile.view_client')
            ->with('message', trans('client.updated'))
            ->with('validation_errors', $errors);
    }
}

/* My current UsersImport class: */

namespace App\Imports;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsFailures;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsOnFailure;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class UsersImport implements WithValidation, SkipsOnFailure, ToCollection
{
    use Importable, SkipsFailures;

    private $clientId;

    public function __construct($clientId)
    {
        $this->clientId = $clientId;
    }


    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        /* this does not work properly: */
        Validator::make($rows->toArray(), $this->rules())->validate();


        /* maybe I need to do something like this: */
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->route('profile.view_client')->with('validation_errors', $validator);
        }

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $user = new User();
            $user->first_name = $row[0];
            $user->last_name = $row[1];
            $user->email = $row[2];
            $user->password = Hash::make(Str::random(16));
            $user->client_id = $this->clientId;
            $user->save();

            DB::table('model_has_roles')->insert([
                'role_id' => 4,
                'model_type' => 'App\User',
                'model_id' => $user->id
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            '*.0' => 'required|max:255',
            '*.1' => 'required|max:255',
            '*.2' => 'required|unique:users,email|email|max:255',
        ];
    }

}
```

Edit: this question was marked as "possible duplicate", but I doubt about it. I tried to write such code in UsersImport class, collection method:

```
    $validator = Validator::make($rows->toArray(), $this->rules());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->route('profile.view_client')
            ->with('validation_errors', $validator->errors());
    }
```

And it does not work at all. I think I know how to write validators in Laravel, and I expect I made very simple mistake somewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate multiple records insertion in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37881490/how-to-validate-multiple-records-insertion-in-laravel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I have solved this problem on myself:

```
<?php

class ProfileController extends Controller
{

    public function updateClient(UserClientRequest $request)
    {
        if (!Auth::user()->hasRole('super-admin') && !Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')) {
            return redirect()->route('profile');
        }

        $client = Auth::user()->client;
        $client->name = $request->name;
        $client->type = $request->type;
        $client->save();

        $errors = [];

        if ($request->hasFile('file_to_import_companies')) {
            $companiesImport = new CompaniesImport($client->id);
            $companiesImport->import($request->file('file_to_import_companies'));
            foreach ($companiesImport->failures() as $failure) {
                foreach ($failure->errors() as $error) {
                    $errors[] = $error;
                }
            }
        }

        // this was changed:
        if ($request->hasFile('file_to_import_users')) {
            $usersImport = new UsersImport($client->id);
            $usersImport->import($request->file('file_to_import_users'));

            // I made function getErrors on UsersImport class:
            $usersValidationErrors = $usersImport->getErrors();
        } else {
            $usersValidationErrors = [];
        }

        $errors = array_merge($errors, $usersValidationErrors);

        return redirect()->route('profile.view_client')
            ->with('message', trans('client.updated'))
            ->with('validation_errors', $errors);
    }
}


/* Here is my UsersImport class: */

namespace App\Imports;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsFailures;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsOnFailure;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\Failure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class UsersImport implements WithValidation, SkipsOnFailure, ToCollection
{
    use Importable, SkipsFailures;

    private $clientId;
    private $errors = []; // array to accumulate errors

    public function __construct($clientId)
    {
        $this->clientId = $clientId;
    }

    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        $rows = $rows->toArray();

        // iterating each row and validating it:
        foreach ($rows as $key=>$row) {
            $validator = Validator::make($row, $this->rules(), $this->validationMessages());
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                foreach ($validator->errors()->messages() as $messages) {
                    foreach ($messages as $error) {
                        // accumulating errors:
                        $this->errors[] = $error;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $user = new User();
                $user->first_name = $row[0];
                $user->last_name = $row[1];
                $user->email = $row[2];
                $user->password = Hash::make(Str::random(16));
                $user->client_id = $this->clientId;
                $user->locale = 'no';
                $user->save();

                DB::table('model_has_roles')->insert([
                    'role_id' => 4,
                    'model_type' => 'App\User',
                    'model_id' => $user->id
                ]);
            }
        }
    }

    // this function returns all validation errors after import:
    public function getErrors()
    {
        return $this->errors;
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            '0' => 'required|max:255',
            '1' => 'required|max:255',
            '2' => 'required|unique:users,email|email|max:255',
        ];
    }

    public function validationMessages()
    {
        return [
            '0.required' => trans('user.first_name_is_required'),
            '1.required' => trans('user.last_name_is_required'),
            '2.required' => trans('user.email_is_required'),
            '2.unique' => trans('user.email_must_be_unique'),
            '2.email' => trans('user.email_must_be_valid'),
        ];
    }

}
```